# How to format Percent value to decimal in VBA

Tags: excel, type-conversion, vba

The decimal values can be converted to percentage values using the function FORMAT but I was wondering if a reverse is possible ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

There is no in built function to convert Percentage to Decimal. 
But the below will help you achieve the same.

```
=IF(LEFT(CELL("format",A1),1)="P",A1)
```